# Running python script with arguments on c# and crashes when on cmd doesn't

Tags: python, c#, cmd, opencv

somehow I'm running a python script with arguments, on cmd works perfectly, but when I pass it through my C# it seems it's not passing the arguments correctly.

Cmd results:

```
C:\Users\Sick\source\repos\phoneScraper\phoneScraper\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Captchas>script.py dztfi.png 
mysycd
```

Code:

```
static string run_cmd(string arg) // arg value = image.png
    {
        string result = ""; 
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Users\Sick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe";//cmd is full path to python.exe
        start.Arguments = "Captchas/script.py " + arg;//args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    c# error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Captchas/script.py", line 11, in <module>
    close = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:757: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'cv::Mat::locateROI'
```

Python code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import sys

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
newkernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
inv = cv2.erode(close, newkernel, iterations=1)

inv = cv2.bitwise_not(inv)

custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(inv, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the WorkingDirectory of ProcessStartInfo. For example you use Application.StartupPath in your application. But that depends where your application starts.
So if you start your app from cmd i think python.exe is running your script. But your applicationstarts in where your scripts.
So try the script give script directory.

```
static string run_cmd(string arg) // arg value = image.png
{
    string result = ""; 
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = @"C:\Users\Sick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe";//cmd is full path to python.exe
    start.Arguments = "Captchas/script.py " + arg;//args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.WorkingDirectory = ""//scriptPath
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For more info visit here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The answer provides the correct solution by using `WorkingDirectory` property which should be `C:\Users\Sick\source\repos\phoneScraper\phoneScraper\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` according to posted `cmd` prompt and used argument `Captchas/script.py`.

Comment: @Mofi , did that, still getting the same crash for some reason.
code: https://paste.sh/8gZcxmLT#OmnUwsIYhvVjLBaJCVFkDiwO

Comment: Well, on running the Python script from command prompt the working directory is `C:\Users\Sick\source\repos\phoneScraper\phoneScraper\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Captchas` containing the files `script.py` and `dztfi.png`. In C# application the working directory for Python script execution is `C:\Users\Sick\source\repos\phoneScraper\phoneScraper\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` and the script file is referenced with `Captchas/script.py` and the PNG file `image.png` which must be stored in working directory and not in Python script directory. Is the PNG file created by C# app? Yes, is the file closed?

Comment: My program saves the image only so yeah, its not open.
Edit, changed a bit what you told me and putted after the image gets save, bitmap.save() and it works now so great. Thanks!